# JPA - transactions not being committed

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

i'm working on a project in which i use JPA, Hibernate and all this stuff for the first time and i ran into problem with transactions not being committed. I use class User which looks like this:

```
 package org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;



@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String login;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private int credit;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String login, String email, String password, int credit) {
        setLogin(login);
        setEmail(email);
        setPassword(password);
        setCredit(credit);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getCredit() {
        return credit;
    }

    public void setCredit(int credit) {
        this.credit = credit;
    }
}
```

and use HSQL database to persist it in MEMORY table. The persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="JBTBackupPersistance">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/database.hsql"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="SA"/> <!--default hsql login-->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="connection.shutdown" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and test it in JUnit test which looks like this:

```
package org.tomasherman.JBTBackup.Resource.Entity;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: arg
 * Date: Jun 29, 2010
 * Time: 11:24:35 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

public class UserTest {
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private EntityManager em;

    private final User u1 = new User("and","now","for",1234);
    private final User u2 = new User("something","completely","different",123123123);
    private final User u3 = new User("a","man","with",123123123);

    @Before
    public void initEmfAndEm() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JBTBackupPersistance");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    @After
    public void cleanup() {
        em.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void emptyTest() {
        System.out.println(em.createQuery("from User").getResultList().size());
        if(em.getTransaction().isActive()){
            System.out.println("FFfffffffffFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
            System.out.println("FFfffffffffFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
            System.out.println("FFfffffffffFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
            System.out.println("FFfffffffffFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
            System.out.println("FFfffffffffFFFFUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
        }else{
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.persist(u1);
            em.persist(u2);
            em.persist(u3);         
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        System.out.println(em.createQuery("from User").getResultList().size());

    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the insert is quite often not written into the database. The output of test looks like this:

```
    ...some hibernate stuff...
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id0_,
        user0_.credit as credit0_,
        user0_.email as email0_,
        user0_.login as login0_,
        user0_.password as password0_ 
    from
        users user0_
20
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (id, credit, email, login, password) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (id, credit, email, login, password) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (id, credit, email, login, password) 
    values
        (null, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id0_,
        user0_.credit as credit0_,
        user0_.email as email0_,
        user0_.login as login0_,
        user0_.password as password0_ 
    from
        users user0_
23
```

so the entites are in the memory of the database, but when i check the database after the unit test, there are no data. It, however, gets committed from time to time.

If anyone could help me, it would be fantastic.

EDIT: 
in case it would help anyone, there is a list of libraries versions(in maven format):

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
      <version>20040616</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

UPDATE2:
Another interesting thing, it seems that if i add Thread.sleep(1000); at the end of the test, all transactions get committed. Could it be that the program finishes faster then the database can be update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the HSQLDB user guide:

> #### [Closing the Database](http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101DB)
>
> From version 1.7.2, in-process
>   databases are no longer closed when
>   the last connection to the database is
>   explicitly closed via JDBC [and data
>   are not written to disk], an explicit
>   `SHUTDOWN` command is required [in
>   order to keep data persistent]. In
>   1.8.0, a connection property, `shutdown=true`, can be specified on
>   the first connection to the database
>   (the connection that opens the
>   database) to force a shutdown when the
>   last connection closes.

So either send that `SHUTDOWN` command through a native query or add **`;shutdown=true`** to the connection string:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:./database/database.hsql;shutdown=true
```

---

Regarding the question about `write_delay`, no, setting it to `0` won't cause a problem in a unit testing context (it "just" has an impact on performances). Actually, I would have expect `shutdown=true` to be enough as mentioned in the documentation:

> #### [Application Development and Testing](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#N13691)
>
> ...
>
> If you do not want to run a Server
>   instance, and you need persistence
>   between tests in different processes,
>   then you should use a `file:`
>   database. You can use the
>   `shutdown=true` connection property to
>   ensure the database is persisted fully
>   after the connections are closed. An
>   alternative option is to use
>   `hsqldb.write_delay=false` connection
>   property, but this is slightly slower
>   than the other option.
>
> It has been reported that some data
>   access frameworks do not close all
>   their connection to the database after
>   the tests. In such situations, you
>   need to use zero WRITE DELAY if you
>   want the data to persist at the end of
>   the tests

But I guess that you are facing the situation described in the second paragraph. I wonder if the data access layer is really guilty though.

Comment: Nit: I think shutdown=true will only work with HSQLDB >= 1.8, but the answer is correct, per documentation on sourceforge : http://hsqldb.sourceforge.net/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101DB.

Comment: hmm i updated the jdbc url according to your suggestion but it made no difference, besides i thought the
        <property name="connection.shutdown" value="true"/>
is equal to what you suggested. Thanks for the post though

Comment: @Arg Doh! I didn't spot the `hibernate.connection.shutdown`. Do you get the same behavior with the previous version of hsqldb (1.8.0.10)? Since you're using maven, it should be pretty easy to test. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually i think i figured it out. In the database.hsql.script was setting "SET FILES WRITE DELAY 500", i changed it to "SET FILES WRITE DELAY 0" and it seems to be working now. Do you think that this could cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `em.getTransaction()` twice, you need to call it once, and save the reference to it. Each time you call it, you get a **new** transaction. So you start one, but then commit a separate one.

Comment: This is not true. The second call gives you the **current** transaction. The code is correct.

Comment: yeah, i actually tried both saving the transaction and using the approach showed in the code and it made no difference, thanks for the post though :]