# JPA Transaction not committed to DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I'm working on a small Spring-Hibernate-Mysql test project and for some reason I my transactions are not getting committed to the DB.

In my application-context I got:

```
<!-- JTA -->

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />

</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />

<!-- JPA -->

<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="persistence/myPU" />

<!-- In order to enable EntityManager injection -->
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="persistenceUnits">
        <map>
            <entry key="myPU" value="persistence/myPU" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/mysqlResource</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I created a simple table called 'persons' in my db:

```
CREATE TABLE persons(
id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
version int, 
full_name VARCHAR(255),
person_id VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255));
```

Created entity a corresponding entity and Dao:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public class Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4349832844316517922L;

/*--- Members ---*/

/**
 * Hibernate genetared UUID
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String id;

@Version
private int version;

@Column(name = "full_name")
private String fullName;

@Column(name = "person_id")
private String personId;

@Column(name = "email")
private String eMail;

/*--- Constructor ---*/

public Person() {
}

/*--- Overridden Methods ---*/

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    if ((obj == null) || !(obj instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }

    // reference comparison
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }

    final Person other = (Person) obj;

    return new EqualsBuilder().append(getPersonId(), other.getPersonId())
            .append(geteMail(), other.geteMail())
            .append(getFullName(), other.getFullName()).isEquals();
}

/**
 * The unique hash code based on the clients' id and citizenship
 * 
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {

    return new HashCodeBuilder().append(geteMail()).append(this.geteMail())
            .append(this.getFullName()).toHashCode();
}

/*--- Getters & Setters ---*/

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public int getVersion() {
    return version;
}

public void setVersion(int version) {
    this.version = version;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

public String getPersonId() {
    return personId;
}

public void setPersonId(String personId) {
    this.personId = personId;
}

public String geteMail() {
    return eMail;
}

public void seteMail(String eMail) {
    this.eMail = eMail;
}
```

}

Dao:

```
@Repository
public class PersonJpaDao extends BasicJpaDao<Person> implements IPersonDao {

public PersonJpaDao() {
    super(Person.class);
}
```

}

here is BasicJpaDao:

```
public class BasicJpaDao<T> implements IBasicDao<T> {

/* --- Members --- */

/** The JPA utility to work with the persistence layer. */
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager entityManager;

/** The type of the entity to which this DAO offers access. */
protected Class<T> entityClass;

/* --- Constructors --- */

/**
 * Default constructor.
 * 
 * @param entityClass
 *            The type of the entity to which this DAO offers access.
 */
public BasicJpaDao(Class<T> entityClass) {
    super();
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}

/* --- Public methods --- */

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void create(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public T read(Object primaryKey) {
    return getEntityManager().find(getEntityClass(), primaryKey);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public T update(T entity) {
    return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void delete(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().remove(entity);
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
@Override
public void flush() {
    getEntityManager().flush();
}

/* --- Getters/Setters --- */

/**
 * @return The JPA utility to work with the persistence layer.
 */
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return this.entityManager;
}

/**
 * @param entityManager
 *            The JPA utility to work with the persistence layer.
 */
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

/**
 * @return The type of the entity to which this DAO offers access.
 */
public Class<T> getEntityClass() {
    return entityClass;
}

/**
 * @param entityClass
 *            The type of the entity to which this DAO offers access.
 */
public void setEntityClass(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}
```

Soo.. basically it works, but nothing gets committed, I mean, if I run

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
private void crearePerson() {
    Person p1 = myDao.read("12345");
    p1.setFullName("kiko too");
    myDao.update(p1);
}
```

I can see (in debug) that p1 gets back from the DB but the update never takes place.
The only close thing I could find was this:

[JPA - transactions not being committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207208/jpa-transactions-not-being-commited)

And I tried adding

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.shutdown" value="true" />
```

to my persistence.xml following this thread but it didn't help.
I also added a property to my connection pool (in my application server gui) called connection.shutdown with the value of true but it didn't help either.

**Update:**
Since I'm using JTA I figured my transaction manager is wrongly configured. While I was using org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager I should have used org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.
So I have changed my application context and now I have:

```
<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Unfortunately, I'm still experiencing the same issue :(
In my console I can see the hibernate query as follows ()I've changed some of my original entity fields, but it doesn't really matters):

INFO: Hibernate: select user0_.id as id0_0_, user0_.email as email0_0_, user0_.full_name as full3_0_0_, user0_.password as password0_0_, user0_.update_by_email as update5_0_0_, user0_.user_name as user6_0_0_, user0_.version as version0_0_ from users user0_ where user0_.id=?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Yogi

Answer (score 3):

The reason it is probably not working is because you are using `@Transactional` on a private method. `@Transactional` will have no effect on a non-public method, because the proxy generator ignores them. From the [Spring Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations):

> **Method visibility and @Transactional**
>
> When using proxies, you should apply the @Transactional annotation
>   only to methods with public visibility. If you do annotate protected,
>   private or package-visible methods with the @Transactional annotation,
>   no error is raised, but the annotated method does not exhibit the
>   configured transactional settings. Consider the use of AspectJ (see
>   below) if you need to annotate non-public methods.

Comment: Thanks! But changing the method visibility did not help,Moreover, I thought that since my class (the one that contains the crearePerson method) implements an interfate that does not define a crearePerson method, spring will not be able to use the transactional annotation. So, I tried two different approaches, the first adding the method declaration to the interface - still not working. Second, adding cglig and declaring <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/> in order for spring to ignore the interface. This didn't help as well. I'm lost here..

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue, and for me the fix came from the following:

In PersistenceXML:

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup">
```

Spring file:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="nameOfUnitInPersistenceXml" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
    <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager" />
</bean>
```

Java class (name the persistence context)

```
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext(name="nameOfUnitInPersistenceXml")
public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add "@Transactional" to your create() method.

edit: it's better practice to put @Transactional at the service layer and not dao layer just fyi

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I do run in a transaction, just edited my question. still can't see my table getting updated after running the code, and I sure agree - the @Transactional annotation should usually take place at the business-logic layer